# Gethostname and IPv6

Tags: c++, windows, networking, ipv6

Microsoft recommends not to use 'gethostname' on IPv6 and instead use 'getaddrinfo' or 'getnameinfo'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899604.aspx

But 'gethostname' doesn't seem to have any problem working on IPv6. Does anyone know any reason why 'gethostname' is not recommended on IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main different is the maximum host name length, `gethostname()` allows 255+1 characters, `getnameinfo()` supports the full DNS length of 1024+1.  If you are using technologies like puny code host names this becomes more pertinent.  Other differences are that you are not guaranteed a FQDN when using `gethostname()`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: +1 Where can you find out about this? I need to improve my Google-Fu :(

Comment: Check the remarks section for each function on MSDN, or the manpage in Unix.